Xcode Splash Screen Transition to App login page visual problems
We've recently updated from cordova-ios version 6 -> 7 and since then we've had issues with The splash image on the app looking weird.  We do generate assets that get populated into the story board but I'm not entirely sure if I missing asset that's causing the transition problem.
Forgive me for not being an IOS developer but I have to work on IOS once in a while.  I'll explain the problem the best I can:
1.  Build the App from Xcode onto an Iphone Pro max 11 emulation
2.  Top level splash screen image gets pulled into view (Looks correct)
3.  App then looks like it's grabbing another image for the splash screen or transition while the rest of app compiles.  This is issue I'm talking about:


I have tried a number of things.  Probably the most noteworthy thing would be following Cordova's Splash Screen documentation.  https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/12.x/core/features/splashscreen/index.html
I've tried the manipulation of the generated images in the Storyboard Asset's ( such as only have a 2x-universal-anyany ) image opposed to using the 3x versions.  I've also tried manually removing the images one by one to see how the splash screen really works.  I've also tried adding in new assets that meet the documentations standard for the iphone idiom.
Below is what the generated splash screens look like without me altering anything:
        <splash src="resources/ios/Default@2x~ipad~comany.png" />
        <splash src="resources/ios/Default@2x~ipad~anycom.png" />
        <splash src="resources/ios/Default@3x~universal~anyany.png" />
        <splash src="resources/ios/Default@1x~universal~anyany.png" />
        <splash src="resources/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />

I'm just curious if anyone else has had this issue or throw out some other suggestions that I can try.

The Cordova document you provided says that they are still using the storyboard-based launch config. So you'd probably need to go into the storyboard and mess around with it. Since you think a Cordova version bump created the problem, I would compare the storyboard files that come from each version.
